# How can I handle user-uploaded photo files for a Rails app (using paperclip) on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, paperclip

So I'm making a Rails app which allows Users to create Items, and each Item has an image attachment, which is handled through the Paperclip gem. The Paperclip gem, by default, saves photos to the public folder, both in original (and thumbnail) form.

I can see how this can get out of hand pretty fast in terms of storage space, given that photos can be fairly big.

My questions:

> 1) How much space will Heroku allow me to hold for images in the public folder?
>
> 2) If Heroku only allows you to hold a finite amount of data in this folder (which I'm sure it does), how can I handle photo storage for a site that will probably have a lot of images? Remotely perhaps? Compression? (Specifics would be nice, as I am completely new to image storage.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku has a read-only file system for your app. Use Amazon S3 to store your uploaded images. [Paperclip has great support for S3](http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/). Check out this [Heroku guide](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Comment: Ok thanks, but can you provide me with some resources or guides so I can figure out how to use Paperclip with S3?

Comment: Also, should I use S3 for my normal Postgres database tables as well?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that other then look up Amazon S3 and read their guides...

Comment: Oh ok, so just one last thing, that article sort of answered my question... it seems the goal is to use S3 as your database instead of a database on Heroku. Yes/no?

Comment: No. Amazon S3 is really for assets. Like images, videos, audio, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, you'll want to use a third party service like S3 and if you do end up using Paperclip then you'll eventually have something like this example in your model.

```
has_attached_file :photo,
        :styles => { :thumb=> "100x100", :small  => "300x300" },
        :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
        :path => "/:id/:style/:filename"
```

And in your config directory you'll have an s3.yml credentials file that would look like:

```
development:
   bucket: blahblah
   access_key_id: sfoi40j8elkfv08hwo
   secret_access_key: DJyWuRtsfoi40j8elkfv08hwos0m8qt

production:
   bucket: blahblah
   access_key_id: sfoi40j8elkfv08hwo
   secret_access_key: DJyWusfoi40j8elkfv08hwos0m8qt
```

Comment: Thanks. Chris's link has this info already. One question though: if I'm supposed to use S3 only for image attachments, does that mean there's an Amazon solution for my database stuff (like all my tables [users, items, products, etc.])? Or should I just not worry about those in terms of reaching capacity? Although these records only contain strings, numbers, and timestamps, it seems like they'll hit a limit at Heroku sooner or later, no?

Comment: No, your database should stay with heroku, and once you've reached your limit you can get the 20gb package for $15 a month. It'll be hard to fill that in a hurry.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was trying to figure out how big each record is in my items table, but it seems it would be negligible.

Comment: Why the database shouldn't go to Amazon? Too expensive?